# How to make section header anchor to the top of a multi section tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know if set the tableView's type to "Plain" , the section header will automatically anchor on the top of the tableView. but if I have multi sections in the tableView. When the tableView scroll to the next section ,the first section's header will disappear. I hope the first section's header can always anchor on the tableView's top whatever I scroll the tableview to any section. is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think you can implement custom UI element which will be simulate section header but will not be part of TableVIew.

Comment: @EvgenLitvinenko yes that's a solution, but  since the section header can automatically suspend below the Navigation bar ,So I want to find a way to set it works on all sections. But now I think there has no way to implement it by system sectionheader.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe does **not** happen for `UITableViewStyleGrouped` but for `UITableViewStylePlain`.

I can't really think of any easy way to do what you want - I suspect you'll have to insert your own subview and manage its position according to the table's scrolling position.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@jeremysh/creating-a-sticky-header-for-a-uitableview-40af71653b55) which might have some good ideas for what you're trying to do.